# Dynamic HTML content is not generated with vanillaJS code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While selecting different values(by using mouse) in a dropdown, different HTML input elements(button, input fields,etc) are generated dynamically.But, when I select different values using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[2].selectedIndex = 5;
```

those HTML input elements(button, input fields,etc) are NOT generated.

The site is in angular1.x

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: Please add code... so we can help you :-)

Comment: We need all the relevant code...Can you please add the code responsible for generating the HTML elements seeing as thats the bit that doesn't work

Comment: It's a pre built website, and I am running my script on it, so cant provide the code which generates dynamic HTML elements.

Comment: Looks like you're manipulating AngularJS elements outside of AngularJS, this isn't going to work. There's probably an ng-model you should update instead of the element's `selectedIndex` directly.

Comment: and how to gain angular context, to manipulate ng-model

Answer (score 1):

VanillaJS changes don't trigger AngularJS's $digest cycle, therefore AngularJS isn't aware of the selectedIndex changed value.

In order to do trigger the cycle, add `$scope.$apply();`, as such:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[2].selectedIndex = 5;
$scope.$apply();
```

That being said, you're not really following AngularJS good practices.
In order to programmatically select a value for selectedIndex you should change the model value of the dropdown.

E.g. You'd have a dropdown with `ng-model` on it

```
<select ng-model="selectedIndex">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And you'd programmatically change the selected value by changing the value of `selectedIndex` in your controller

```
app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.changeSelection = function (index) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    }
});
```